# show that infinite intersection of sets intersected with compact set K is nonempty

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Let $K$ be a compact subset of $ \mathbb R^d$ and let $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset \cdots \subset A_k$ be a nested downward sequence of closed subsets of $\mathbb R^d$. Show that if $A_k \cap K \neq \emptyset $ for each $k$, then $(\bigcap A_k) \cap K \neq \emptyset$.

attempt at solution: We will prove by contradiction. Thus suppose on the contrary that $(\bigcap A_k) \cap K = \emptyset.$ Suppose that $A_k \cap K \neq \emptyset$ for each $k$.

My idea is to use the definition of compactness to show that both expressions don't work. But I'm not exactly sure where to start with using compactness and what type of thing I should expect to be the contradiction.

Hints and Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First thing to notice is that you have not formed the negation correctly. Secondly, this approach likely isn't going to work out very well; try noticing that $A_k \cap K$ is a compact set (why?) and so you can reduce this to the statement "a nested sequence of compact sets has non-empty intersection," which is easier to deal with.

Comment: Normally $\cap$ is used in expressions like $A\cap B$ and $A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n$ and $\bigcap$ is used in things like $\bigcap_{j=1}^k A_j$ and $\displaystyle\bigcap_{j=1}^k A_j.$ I edited accordingly.

Comment: When you write $A_1\subset\cdots\subset A_k,$ it appears that $k$ is the largest value of the index, but in the expression $\bigcap_k A_k,$ you seem to mean $k$ runs through the whole set of indices. I'd use two different letters for that.

Comment: $A_1 \subset \cdots \subset A_k$ is an ascending sequence, not a descending sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need a descending sequence, thus $A_1 \supset A_1 \supset A_3\supset \cdots$ with $\text{“}\supset\text{''}$ rather than $\text{“}\subset\text{''}.$

These subsets are closed, so their respective complements $B_1 \subset B_2\subset B_3\subset \cdots$ are open.

If no point in $K$ is in all of $A_k,\, k = 1,2,3,\ldots,$ then every point in $K$ is in one of $B_k,\,k=1,2,3\ldots;$ that is de Morgan's law. Thus $\{B_k : k=1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is an open cover of $K,$ and by compactness, has a finite subcover $\{B_{k_1}, \ldots, B_{k_m}\},$ and we may take the indices to be in increasing order: $k_1<\cdots<k_m.$ Since every point in $K$ is in one of $B_{k_1},\ldots,B_{k_m},$ no point in $K$ is in $A_{k_1},\ldots, A_{k_m}.$ Thus we have
$$
A_{k_1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{k_m} = \varnothing.
$$
But since $A_{k_1} \supset \cdots \supset A_{k_m},$ we then have $A_{k_m} = \varnothing,$ contrary to a hypothesis.